# Vertical bricks above a window new house uk

Tags: windows, safety, drill, brick, masonry

I am trying to fit an outdoor camera above my window frame. The beat place for me is in the line of vertical tiles above the frame. These seems to only have half thickness and I am not sure what is behind them. Any advice if I am supposed to drill into the masonry work above the window? This is a new build uk house.

Thank you

Comment: Pictures? Ask the builder?

Comment: Probably some sort of lintel reinforcement (with "half-thickness" brick) - could be a steel beam, could be reenforced concrete, it's a new build so your builder should be able to tell you.

Comment: Bricks or tiles ? Which? Makes a difference.

Comment: Probably a metal catnic above the frame, behind the bricks. Not the best place to drill.